# Spring insecuremvc - sample files location?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring with: gradle, annotations (not xml), springboot, embedded server. Followed the guides of the side; they are great. Now I wanted to try it myself. I am creating a simple MVC (however I do not understand the difference between MVC and web-MVC entirely) - and want to add 'security'.

This example 'insecuremvc' (is maven, is war; instead of gradle/jar; but it is available). I could make it run.

However, where are the sources? I wanted to see them to learn it. It runs in my localhost, magically if said so, only by poms and downloaded jars - while, I could not find the jar of insecuremvc or such.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341665/how-to-run-the-spring-security-samples-from-command-line-instead-of-from-sts) did not help. Is there anything fundamental that I have missed?

Comment: WAR file is a web archive, it does not have sources, maybe you should contact the developer who can give you the sources.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, and thank you for the hint about WAR; however, I can extract a JAR, when I have it. Where is this WAR?

Comment: If you say so, if you would have just Googled, it would have been the same.

Comment: thank you, after your hint, I searched more, and found it. It's here (maybe someone will look for it later, also) . However I still don't understand how this sample runs, if there are not sources, no WAR either. (and it's jsp, anyhow, instead of thymeleaf). Sources: https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/samples/insecuremvc/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/messages/inbox.jspx?r=976d9a90166158d46b3dff9016719e871ccbeb5b

Comment: https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/buildSrc/src/main/groovy   There goes your source code in Groovy language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont have sources located in a WAR file as it means a web-archive. You can use the below link to get your sources which are in Groovy.

[Source code](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-security/buildSrc/src/main/groovy)

If there is anything else, let me know.